Italian movie, a large olive oil pot and boat trip to a floating island
About 35 years ago (+/- 5 years), I saw an Italian movie on television that made a strong impact on me (a small child back then). I'm not really much into movies but I've been asking around and searched the net. I've also watched one or tho movies that people suggested, but no hit so far. Does anyone have a clue of what it was? As I don't know any names, it's very hard to find it. 
Judging from how I remember the visual language and light, the movie could be from the 70's or early 80's. Maybe older, but good technical quality. 
I think the story takes place between 1890-1940 and probably in southern Italy.  Sicily maybe. It might be a story about many generations of the same family and some kind of spell that follow them, but I'm not sure about that.As I wasn't old when I watched it, I only remember random scenes, the context and story I didn't understand. 
Some scenes I remember:
A man repairs a large pot to store olive oil, he glues and sew it together from the inside, but become trapped and the owner (?) of the olive farm don't let him out. He stays in the pot during night and it's raining. Finally the pot cracks (a thunderbolt?) and he gets out. 
A mighty (older maybe) man squeezes an olive on the face (forhead?) of a (young?) beautiful woman. She says: 'Clean it up!' and he licks up the olive oil from her face. 
A family goes on a boat trip. They have bright clothes and are sailing on the green sea. Suddenly the arrive to a floating cinder island and go ashore and play with tephra from a volcano. A speaker voice explains that they found a floating Island, maybe an old memory from a brighter time. 
I'm grateful for any hints. 

Answering my own question... A colleague of mine knew it and that it was based on Pirandello's texts.
It's called Kaos, by Vittorio and Paolo Taviani. Based on Pirandello's short stories. 
Highly recommended, now I'll find it and watch it again. 
